# logged on users in array or object (powershell, command line)

Tags: powershell, command-line

I have few Windows Server 2012 R2 with RDS installed and I need to have function which returns array or object with users and their session IDs on specified server. I need to run this function with non-admin permissions. On the session hosts I ran this command:

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\CIMV2\TerminalServices PATH Win32_TSPermissionsSetting WHERE     (TerminalName ="RDP-Tcp") CALL AddAccount "domain\group",2
```

...so the users have elevated permissions and now they can use RDS shadowing through command line. The ID which I need is the session ID which I can get for example from command "quser". The best solution will be if I will have function which returns array (with logged on users on the specific server) like this (or something similar, maybe object):

```
    LOGIN    ID
    user1 -> 3
    user2 -> 4
    user3 -> 5
```

I don't know if this function or these commands will solve my problem, however I tried them and this was the result:

I tried this:
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-UserSessions-Parse-b4c97837
but the command returns nothing.

This command:

```
WMIC /NODE:<COMPUTERNAME> COMPUTERSYSTEM GET USERNAME
```

returns only "UserName" and this:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select UserName
```

..returns only "UserName" with underlines. I tried a lot of variations of WMI commands, but with similar results.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a half dozen scripts in various repositories around the 'net to do that.
I use this one:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/0e43993a-895a-4afe-a2b2-045a5146048a

Comment: I tried tons of scripts or commands I found on the net, but nothing solved my issue. Something does not work at all and something does not work in the way I need. This script returns a lot of mess, like services etc. I need only logged on users and their session IDs in the array or object.

Comment: You're going to have to do better than "something does not work".  Nobody knows how to fix that.  If you go to someone for help, don't make them have to play 20 Questions trying to figure out what you need help with.  Update your question with something specific enough to give us something to work with.

Comment: I purposely didn't write down the commands that didn't work, because I don't know if they are what I need. I wanted to avoid situation, when we will deal with any command which does not work for me and after long time when the command will be finally working I will find out that this not solve my issue. Nevertheless I updated my question with some commands that didn't work for me...

Comment: The script in the link returns all the logons, including the service logons. If you want just the interactive user logons, it's trivial to filter those out with where-object.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to mention, that I need to run this function as non-admin user and the script in the link returns only user who runs that script and also the ID is different. I need the ID which I can use for RD shadowing...

Comment: Do you mean you need it to use alternate credentials?

Comment: No no... I need to run it with regular user permissions. This function will be part of the script with GUI frontend which will be used by 30 people. They will use RD shadowing through this tool. This is necessary workaround, because Windows Server 2012 R2 does not provide shadowing for regular users...

Comment: It will only do what the user running the script has permissions to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
gwmi -query "Select * from Win32_LogonSession where LogonType = 2" | 
% {
    $user = $_
    gwmi -query "Associators of {$user} Where AssocClass=Win32_LoggedOnUser" | select *
}
```

Comment: You might need to be an admin. Also, please try to play with it a little bit-- this is the exact WMI API that any Windows Administration tool would use, so it does work.